# How to get PCM 16-bit data from TarsosDSP AudioDispatcher?

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, tarsosdsp

I want to get PCM 16-bit data from TarsosDSP AudioDispatcher. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231813/tarsosdsp-pitch-analysis-for-dummies/31248698#31248698) for the pitch analysis of a real-time audio stream. I am getting the desired results but I also want to get the PCM data from AudioDispatcher.

```
AudioDispatcher adp = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(2048, 0);
```

How can I get the required PCM data from AudioDispatcher or any other technique to pass my data from the android AudioRecord to AudioDispatcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your audioRecorder object to **AudioDispatcherFactory** by simply creating your own **AudioDispatcherFactory.java** class with extra argument of **AudioRecorder**

Like this:

```
package com.example.revertback;

public class AudioDispatcherFactory {


public static AudioDispatcher fromDefaultMicrophone(final AudioRecord audioInputStream,final int sampleRate,
                                                    final int audioBufferSize, final int bufferOverlap) {
    int minAudioBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
            android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    int minAudioBufferSizeInSamples =  minAudioBufferSize/2;
    if(minAudioBufferSizeInSamples <= audioBufferSize ){

        TarsosDSPAudioFormat format = new TarsosDSPAudioFormat(sampleRate, 16,1, true, false);

        TarsosDSPAudioInputStream audioStream = new AndroidAudioInputStream(audioInputStream, format);
        //start recording ! Opens the stream.
        return new AudioDispatcher(audioStream,audioBufferSize,bufferOverlap);
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size too small should be at least " + (minAudioBufferSize *2));
    }
}



public static AudioDispatcher fromPipe(final String source,final int targetSampleRate, final int audioBufferSize,final int bufferOverlap){
    PipedAudioStream f = new PipedAudioStream(source);
    TarsosDSPAudioInputStream audioStream = f.getMonoStream(targetSampleRate,0);
    return new AudioDispatcher(audioStream, audioBufferSize, bufferOverlap);
}
}
```

And in your Activity do some this like this

```
AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();
  AudioDispatcher dispatcher = com.example.revertback.AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(recorder,22050,1024,0);


    PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult result, AudioEvent e) {
            final float pitchInHz = result.getPitch();

        }
    };
    AudioProcessor p = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(p);
    new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher").start();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Abubakar.  It is working but could you please tell me another way to get byte data from tarsos?